# How to use Gnome Photos to browse my Pictures folder?

Tags: 16.04, gnome

Gnome comes with [Gnome Photos](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Photos) which is supposed to be super simple to use so I feel like an idiot asking, but... where are my pictures?

I have thousands of JPEGs in my Pictures folder, but "Photos" is empty?

Comment: Isn't Gnome Photos for online services only?

Comment: According to its [design objectives](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/Apps/Photos) it is supposed to work locally, too.